# ClojureScript, Heroku - Connect to Postgres Database

Tags: clojurescript, expo

I have a simple postgres database running on heroku. I read about how to externally access a heroku postgres database, using the config options and `DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a app) process` (so I have the location, login details etc)

However, as the Expo app is all ClojureScript, how do I connect to the Postgres Database?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it's not currently possible to connect directly to a Postgres database in pure JavaScript/Clojurescript, which means that you're not able to do it inside an Expo app.

In general, you don't want to connect directly to your database from a mobile or web app. See, for example, information about multi-tier application architectures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Web_development_usage

Answer (score 1):

The [SQLingvo.node](https://github.com/r0man/sqlingvo.node) library accomplishes the use of node-postgres/pg-native from ClojureScript by using cljs.nodejs

```
(def pg
  "The Node.js PostgreSQL client."
  (let [package (node/require "pg")]
    (or (.-native package) package)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to run the pure-JavaScript variant of [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) in the browser?